# Get current month full name in android

Tags: android

In my project, i have a spinner for choose month and I want to display current month as default selected. I have string array in `string.xml` .

```
<string-array name="Months">
        <item>January</item>
        <item>February</item>
        <item>March</item>
        <item>April</item>
        <item>May</item>
        <item>June</item>
        <item>July</item>
        <item>August</item>
        <item>September</item>
        <item>October</item>
        <item>November</item>
        <item>December</item>
    </string-array>
```

In MainActivity, I set adapter to the spinner,

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> monthAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.Months, R.layout.spinner_item);
        monthAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        spnMonth.setAdapter(monthAdapter);
        spnMonth.setSelection(Util.setCurrentMonthSpinner(context));
```

In `Util.java` I use these two functions, these function are static because the functions are used in many activities.

```
public static int setCurrentMonthSpinner (Context context) {
        String[] months = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Months);
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            String mnth = Util.getCurrentMonth();
            if (months[i].equals(mnth))
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and second method is...

```
public static String getCurrentMonth () {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMM");

        return month_date.format(cal.getTime());
    }
```

The method getCurrentMonth returns current month name like Jan or Feb but i want to get return String like January or February. Guide me...

Comment: Hi @userJP, I check your function and I am getting full name in it as January, October and all

Comment: @Vickyexpert String[] months contains full name because it initialize in string.xml but method Util.getCurrentMonth(); not return full month name.

Comment: why you change format from "MMMM" to "MMMMM" ? , "MMMM" was working fine I had check it

Comment: hey @Vickyexpert my code use "MMMMMM" which returns first 3 character but i post it "MMMMM". after your comment i check it again my code and debug it returns 3 characters. then i change it to "MMMMM" as you mention your code works perfectly but you are wrong. it return only 1st character of current month.

Comment: Bye the way, you give me the answer, "MMMM" works perfectly. Thank you @Vickyexpert

Comment: "MMMM" this will work not 5 or 6 M

Comment: yep exactly enjoy coding

Comment: It's weird that `MMMMMM` works well here http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/, but will return as an upper-cased first character of the month name when running on android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a locale to your SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int month = 
    c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
switch(month){
case 0:
    return R.string.january;
    break;

}
```

Note that this method starts with index 0 and ends at index 11 where 0 is January and 11 is December. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: You are right but this is not smart coding.. why i use switch case, if there is method of 2 or 3 lines for the same output.

Comment: When I code, I go by a simple saying: If A doesn't work, use B. If your method does not work, use something else. It is not the most efficient thing in terms of length, but it works.